# Switching between different ruby install and gemset using rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I recently installed ruby 2.0.0 using rvm and also created a new gemset for this install. I noticed that whenever I switch to ruby 1.9.3 (my old installed version), it knows to use the gemset that I created for that version of ruby.

My only problem is that when I switch to ruby 2.0 it does not know that it has to use the gemset that I created for that particular installation. Is there a way to setup rvm such that it automatically loads my gemset when the ruby version is switched.

In short, I am trying to avoid doing this

```
rvm use 2.0.0
rvm gemset use rails-4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create RVM alias:

```
rvm alias create rails-4.0 2.0.0@rails-4.0
```

use it with:

```
rvm rails-4.0
```

You can also set rails-4.0 gemset default to Ruby 2.0.0 with:

```
rvm use 2.0.0@rails-4.0 --default
```

Comment: is aliasing the only option? I guess rvm does not have any way of doing this automatically.